# "Cannot resolve symbol............." issue in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am beginner in developing test automation for Mobile apps, and already I am facing "Cannot resolve symbol........." issues. I have also done a "sync to Gradle".

I have a MainActivityTest class which consist of the following :

[image: ,]
As can be seen, the red-colored texts are giving me the issues of "Cannot resolve symbol  when mouse-over them.

The following is the Gradle in my app module
[image]

Hope to have advice as what have I done wrong.

Comment: Are you missing your package at the top? 'package com.example.myfiristapp'

Comment: @shb I have specify to use default package. I thought it was the same with Eclispe, where if one did not define package, then there is no need for the package declaration ? Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yeah, that works.

Comment: @shb I still have to add the package ?

Comment: That just caught my eye at first glance. Not necessary it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Steps you can explore:

Step 1: `File` > `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

Step 2: If it doesn't work even now, `File` > `Invalidate Caches and Restart`.

Step 3: After you restart, you can *Clean* Project, *Rebuild* Project.

Another Step: `File` > `Close Project`, and reopen it.

Edit:

If you didn't find any solution to the problem with the above steps you can follow the following steps.

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Let Us consider your project name is ' ***AndroidProject*** '.
3. Go to your project folder (...../***AndroidProject***/). It will have `app/`, `build/`, `gradle/`, `release/` folders and `build.gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradle.properties`, 'gradle.bat`,` settings.gradle`,` local.properties` files.
4. Delete the `build/` folder. (Don't worry nothing is going to happen! This folder is something that is generated).
5. Now navigate into `app/`, and delete the `build/` folder in that as well.
6. Open Android studio now. The project will rebuild. Your errors will be gone.

Comment: I have tried your method, and found some errors. Hope you can shed some light. Here is a video of what I have done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy6SIEEu7wg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: At the very end of the video you can see an option *"Apply Gradle plugin"*. Please select this option and sync the gradle files again. This problem may be due to the old gradle version, not upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: @Tester_at_work please go through the new updated steps.