# Cannot resolve symbol 'java' build.gradle file

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, groovy

the first line in my build.gradle file is `import java.nio.file.Files`  and android studio shows this error "cannot resolve symbol 'java' ". I've tried manupilating SDK versions and the common stuff online yet no answer to be found.
Here's a snippet:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI7Qe.png]

Comment: @Crebain nope, thanks anyway

Comment: Please check "Run" or "Build" window in Android Studio, there should be more detailed error message.

Comment: Maybe the first answer from here will help you: ["Cannot resolve symbol............." issue in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175102/cannot-resolve-symbol-issue-in-android-studio)